# What is the difference List<String> list = new LinkedList<>() vs List list = new LinkedList<String>()?

Tags: java

I found a problem when I am using java generics.

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add(MyObject);  //No
```

prompts for any compilation errors.This  is not I want

If I use :

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(MyObject); //Prompt for compilation errors.This is what I want
```

I wanna know what is the difference between

`List<String> list = new LinkedList<>()` and
`List list = new LinkedList<String>()` and 
`List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>()` and
`List<String> list = new LinkedList()`?

Comment: hi guys ,
   I found a problem when I am using java generics.
   List list = new LinkedList<String>()
   list.add(MyObject)  ,//No prompts for any compilation errors.This  is not I want

   If I use :
   List<String> list = new LinkedList<>()
   list.add(MyObject) ,//Prompt for compilation errors.This is what I want

I wanna to know what is the difference List<String> list = new LinkedList<>() vs List list = new LinkedList<String>() vs List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>() vs List<String> list = new LinkedList()?

Comment: stackoverflow has a bug for post <String>

Comment: No it hasn't.  Any `<` or `>`  characters in normal markdown text need to be escaped or they are likely to be treated as unrecognized html elements and "disarmed".  Solution: use back-quotes or code blocks.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and pay attention to them.  The compiler will tell you why you cannot omit the `<…>`.

Answer (score 3):

`List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();` does the following:

1. Declare a variable called `list` with type `List<String>`
2. Call the constructor of `LinkedList` with the type parameter `String`
3. Sets the value of `list` to the result of step 2.

Since a `List<String>` is obviously not going to be given a `new LinkedList<Elephant>();`, it is OK to remove the type parameter from the second part, giving: `List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();`. This is called "Type Inference". Java can only do this when it can calculate at compile-time what the omitted type would be.

If you use `List list = new LinkedList<String>();`, you do exactly the same thing as above, except your new variable `list` does not contain type information. This can be dangerous, as it prevents the compiler from warning/stopping you when you do something that would cause a type error.

For example:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("hello");  // works fine
list.add(123);  // compile-time error
```

I have been saved from putting an `int` into a list of `String`s. However, if using a regular `List`:

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("hello");  // stil works
list.add(123);  // also works
```

The issue with this comes from when you then retrieve items from the list:

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add(123);  // allowed
Object obj = list.get(0);  // is obj a String? is it an int?
```

This breaks type safety, which is arguably a strong reason for using Java in the first place.